# Exiting WorksheetChange if Data Validation Cell is Invalid

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am currently building an Excel database that uses **WorksheetChange** to perform several automations when a user enters data, one of which is **Application.Undo**. However, I also have data validation cells. When I input an invalid entry into a cell with data validation and click "Cancel", the cell is returned to its previous state and *then* the WorksheetChange function is run, where I get an **Application.Undo Error** due to whatever code was run for the data validation cell. Is there a way to determine if data validation has occurred?

When I try using Target.Validation.Value, it always returns True because the data validation has already reset the value to its previous state, which is a valid value. What I think would be the easiest solution is to have code like this:

If Target Cell Data Validation Occurred And Was Invalid Then
Exit Sub
End

Obviously, I am looking for what code might allow me to make this If statement. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe trap the error for `Application.Undo` and make a decision based on that.  Would help to show your actual code.

Comment: What do you mean you "click cancel" when entering invalid data?  Are you entering data into a cell, or a field on a form?  Do you mean that you're hitting the Esc key to cancel your input into a cell?

Comment: @TimWilliams The problem is I don't know how to "trap" the Application.Undo to not execute if the data validation error occurs. That code executes prior to WorksheetChange, and does not cause an error that would route my VBA code to ErrHandler. I was wondering if there is a way to identify the answer to the following question: did the user just input an invalid response that caused the data validation code to revert the cell to its previous value?

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor When you enter a value into a data validation cell that is not valid, you get an error box that tells you the data is not valid, which you then click "Cancel" or "Retry". That part is less important. Excel is running some VBA code for the data validation that takes precedent over the WorkSheet_Change code I have, which is messing up my Application.Undo. I was wondering if there is a way to know if the user had entered invalid data into the target cell, so I can just exit the Worksheet_Change sub.

Comment: Not sure of the specifics of your situation, but can you move data validation work to VBA rather than Excel?  Then, if the entered data was invalid, VBA could disable events so that you wouldn't trigger your `Application.Undo` event.

Comment: If you uncheck the option for "Show error after invalid data is entered" then you can check `Target.Validation.Value` in the change event handler.  It will be False if the user has entered an invalid value.

Comment: @Ted Williams: Didn't know this. You should post this as answer, maybe plus the error trapping as alternative.

Comment: Your validation should have occurred before any cells were changed in your data.  Instead of taking an approach where your code is trying to handle the errors while inserting the information, take the approach where you make sure that the data is valid prior to changing your data.  Most developers will tell you that about 25% of their code is data validation, because it's a whole lot easier to keep the garbage out early than it is to handle it late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up the Data Validation, if you uncheck the option for "Show error after invalid data is entered" then you can check `Target.Validation.Value` in the change event handler. It will be `False` if the user has entered an invalid value, and you can handle that case as you want.

Comment: One last question. Is there a quicker way (other than iterating through all data validated cells) to turn off all error messages? I have over 40 sheets with ~100 columns each, each with their own unique error message. Thanks!

Comment: This for example: `Range("E22").Validation.ShowError = False` would be equivalent to unchecking the box in the DV setup dialog.   I don't think there's any "global" setting though....  You'd need to write a loop to do that.